# Error in eigen(A) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r

I am using the function `sr.loc.test` from the `SpatialNP` package in R.

I'm doing a 2 sample test . I'm getting an error stating

> "Error in eigen(A) : infinite or missing values in 'x' "

But there's no missing value in any of the 2 samples.

Can you suggest a solution ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example which reproduces your error.

Comment: It might help to read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248).